# jQuery - Fixed Navigation not working in IE

Tags: jquery, animation, navigation

I am working from this tutorial: http://www.distractedbysquirrels.com/blog/one-page-layout-with-fixed-navigation-and-jquery/

Here is the demo: http://demo.distractedbysquirrels.com/one_page_fixed_nav/

It does not work in Internet Explorer - does anyone have any idea how to fix it to work in IE?

Thanks
Zach

Comment: You mean, doesn't work in IE6 I think because it seems to work OK iin IE7, IE8 and IE9....

Comment: It doesn't work in IE9 for me by default. It only works if I enable the developer tools and refresh the page. document.ready() issue?

Comment: I dosen't work in IE8 for me.

Comment: When I enable developer tools, then it works.  How can I make it work by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue I can see is the lack of a console.log facility that may annoy IE.  This could be patched up by adding this code fragment:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(typeof console === "undefined") {
        console = {
            log: function() { }
        };
    }
</script>
```